# writing XML data to an ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, xml

I want to show my data on an ASP.NET page using C# in XML format

```
<person>
    <email>a@a.com</email>
    <dob>YYYY-MM-DD- HH:MM:SS</dob>
    <city>XYZ</city>
</person>
```

Do you have any code with examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

format your string in Html

then add the values there and

add

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("content-type", "text/xml");
```

then write the string to browser

```
    response.write(yourstring);
```

example --

```
        string str = "<root>" + "<person>" + personName + "</person>";
        str += "<details>";
        str += "<DOB>" + "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" + "</DOB>";
        str += "<City> " + "XYZ" + "</City>";
        str += "</details>";
        str += "</root>";
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("content-type", "text/xml");
        Response.Write(str);
        Response.End();
```

Comment: Constructing it as a string is a very bad idea because it will be invalid when data isn't escaped properly.

Answer (score 2):

I am giving you a generic solution

Create a class
**

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string DOB { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
```

**

After that write this method in your any class library like that

```
Public Class Utilities
{
    public static XmlElement Serialize(object transformObject)
            {
                XmlElement serializedElement = null;
                try
                {
                    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(transformObject.GetType());
                    serializer.Serialize(memStream, transformObject);
                    memStream.Position = 0;
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.Load(memStream);
                    serializedElement = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
                }
                catch (Exception SerializeException)
                {

                }
                return serializedElement;
            }
```

}

Now write this main function at your page , where you want make this task

```
private void MainMethod()
{
Collection<Person> mPersons = new Collection<Person>();
            //Fill your collection object mPersons with data 
            // I am giving here example for demo
            Person sPerson = new Person();
            sPerson.City = "City 1";
            sPerson.DOB = DateTime.Now.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"); //just for example 
            sPerson.Email = "email_1@email.com";
            mPersons.Add(sPerson);
            //add another class object
            sPerson = new Person();
            sPerson.City = "City 2";
            sPerson.DOB = DateTime.Now.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"); //just for example 
            sPerson.Email = "email_2@email.com";
            mPersons.Add(sPerson);

            XmlElement xE = (XmlElement)Utilities.Serialize(mPersons);
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.LoadXml(xE.OuterXml.ToString());
            xDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("myFile.xml"));//give your file path name may be in your web application folder   

}
```

Try this, if you have class object or dataset

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use repeater Control. In this control add table to its ItemTemplate. And after button click Bind The xmlDataSource to this repeater

```
  <table>
     <ItemTamplate>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="3"><person></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><email><%#Bind('email')%></email></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td></td> <td></td> <td><dob><%#Bind('date')%></dob></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td> <td></td> <td><city><%#Bind('city')%></city></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="3"></email></td>
      </tr>
    </person>
    </ItemTamplate>
    </table>
```

Comment: why? my created Table Template will show it as xml. Why you think that it will not show in xml format in browser?

Answer (score 1):

using System;
using System.Xml;
namespace WriteXmlFile
{
    class Class1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // first you have to create the xml file to any location
            XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("D:\TestxmlFile.xml", null);
            // to write any things you have to  Opens the document
            textWriter.WriteStartDocument();

`// Write first element
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Person");
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("r", "RECORD", "urn:record");
        // Write next element
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Email", "");
        textWriter.WriteString("DOB");
        textWriter.WriteString("City");
        textWriter.WriteEndElement();
        // WriteChars
        string[] ch = new string[3];
        ch[0] = "a@a.com";
        ch[1] = "YYYY-MM-DD";
        ch[2] = "xyz";
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Char");
        textWriter.WriteChars(ch, 0, ch.Length);
        textWriter.WriteEndElement();
        // Ends the document.
        textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
        // close writer
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}`

}

Then after that you will find out the desired output

Comment: Question was how to output it to the browser, not to save it to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I find it better to use a real XML document object serverside, so that you are sure you are passing a valid XML to the browser.

Something like this :

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml("<xmlcontent />");

Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=filename.xml");
xml.Save(Response.OutputStream);
```